# Low latency midi and Virtual sound studio

Tags: sound, music, midi

I wish to connect my musical keyboard to linux (figured that part out)
But I would like to know my options for Virtual Grand Pianos.

Answer (score 1):

The [Linux MultiMedia Studio](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/) (open source) and the [EnergyXT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVyD1.png) (closed source, running natively under Linux) mentioned in **[this answer](http://www.energy-xt.com/)**, is great for Music creators/producers and even performers. Placed here just for your convenience:

> You can use both the [**Linux MultiMedia Studio**](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/) (lmss) at  which
>   seems to be an alternative or similar software to Fruity Loops, Sony
>   Acid, etc. It allows you to sample audio files, insert percussions,
>   read/write midi's, etc.
>
> If you are familiar to Fruity Loops,Sony Acid and these style of
>   software you will feel comfortable with LMMS.
>
> Screenshot provided right here for your convenience:
>
> [image]
>
> Another great sound work station is the [**Energy XT**](http://www.energy-xt.com/), which is
>   indeed proprietary (closed source), running natively on linux and
>   these days they have a "free" version which allows you to do some
>   limited things like saving but including only 1 synth, 3 percussions
>   and these things. The fancy of this is that it is really easy to use
>   and it runs natively on linux.
>
> Videos can be reached right here:
>   http://www.energy-xt.com/index.php?id=0101
>
> And a screenshot from my desktop for you to see the full version of
>   energyXT at work is also here:
>
> [image]
>
> Both these are ready to run, but if you wish try finding alternatives
>   to these applications, I suggest you this site:
>   http://alternativeto.net/ on which you can perform searching for
>   almost any known application.

Additionally, the LMMS Wiki related to Midi, can be helpful for you, reach it right here: http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/0.4:Using_MIDI

I have tried some midi keyboards in the past, unfortunately I don't have them right now to run a test for you but I experienced some issues the first times and had to patch a few things in order to get the keyboard fully working. And I couldn't fix a major issue with a model, which I can't remember (I don't own it anymore), as the instructions were about to patch the keyboard's firmware itself.

I hope your midi keyboard is more compatible than these that I owned in the past. And if you provide further information about your keyboard's brand name and model it would be really helpful.

Good luck!

Comment: I knew about LMMS but i never even though to check the wiki. (trivial but, i forgot) And thanks for the info, very handy.